# Excel VBA Macro: set source data as separate columns

Tags: vba, excel, charts, excel-formula

I am trying to update the data range source for a chart in VBA, dynamically and for multiple separate columns. Below the details:

```
Sub ChartValue2()

Dim rg As Range
Dim i As Integer

i = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
Set rg = Range("$A$1", Range("$A$1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))

ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select

ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("rg.Columns(1), rg.Columns(3)")

End Sub
```

[image: AS in the picture my code will select the whole range from column 1 to column 3. Instead what i want to achieve is to source column 1 & 3 separately. Thanks in advance.]

As you can see in the image, my code is selecting the whole range from column 1 to 3, but what I want is to select column 1 & 3 separately.

How can I do this?

Comment: Dim r as Range
Dim e as Range
Dim i as Integer
Set r = Range("A1")

For i = 1 to 3
 e = r.Offset(0, i)
'Do something with e
Next i

Comment: Oh no!! Sorry the question disappeared. My question is: As you can see in the image, my code is selecting the whole range from column 1 to 3. What I am trying to achieve is to select column 1 & 3 separately. Any suggestions? thanks a lot

Comment: Perhaps this instead `ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Union(rg.Columns(1), rg.Columns(3))` - try playing around with the union bit as not sure which regions you want.

Comment: @SJR Your suggestion works great!! Thanks everybody for the help.